# AWS Dynamo DB Free Tier Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, open-source, lwc

I am new to DynamoDB, and I have a small in house application, which will be used by my parents for their small business. I just have to keep records of 10 - 20 rows daily, and will have a few edits close to 5 - 10 at max.
WIll I be able to use the Free Tier of Dynamo DB for the same?

I am using Heroku to host my LWC OSS (Node JS) application, which is again a free version. If not then any heads up to any particular type of Database which can fulfil my need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will I be able to use the Free Tier of Dynamo DB for the same?

**Yes, dependent on the size of the data you want to be inputting & the rate at which you want to input.**

Amazon DynamoDB offers a [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=categories%23databases&all-free-tier.q=Amazon%2BDynamoDB&all-free-tier.q_operator=AND) with the following provisions, which is enough to handle up to 200M requests per month:

1. 25 GB of Storage
2. 25 provisioned Write Capacity Units (WCU)
3. 25 provisioned Read Capacity Units (RCU)

Just be aware of the fact that:

- 25 WCU is 25 writes per second for an item up to 1KB or 5 writes per second for an item up to 5KB etc.
- 25 RCU is 50 reads per second for an item up to 4KB or 10 reads per second for an item up to 20KB etc.

If your API calls fall within the above criteria, you'll be within the free tier.

Comment: My data size will be very less, and the input rate will also be very less.

Answer (score 2):

The main costed aspects of DynamoDB are how much you read and write to the tables. AWS call them "Read capacity units" (RCU) and "Write capacity units" (WCU).

When you create a DynamoDB table there are many options to choose from, but it's roughly accurate to say that:

- One RCU gives you one strongly consistent read request per second
- One WCU gives you one standard write request per second

So if you create a [standard class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.tableclasses.html) table with 1 RCU and 1 WCU (the lowest possible) that would already easily accomodate what you predict you will need.
According to the AWS DynamoDB [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) you can get 25 WCUs and 25 RCUs in the free tier.

So I would say choose DynamoDB standard class table, with Provisioned Capacity, no Auto Scaling, and customized to 1 RCU and 1 WCU like below, and your usage will remain well within the free tier.

[image]

Comment: I would still run with auto-scaling but set the max for maybe 5-10, just in case. Let's say 1.5 years from now things change. I'd hate to have traffic throttled just for going over the 1 and 1 capacity units. With settings like that, if something bumps up above the free tier, it shouldn't charge you much.